# Maximum filename length shorter in search windows than same file in original folder

Tags: windows-7

Why can a mp3 file-name  be 165 characters long in its original folder, but when searching  that folder, the search results window only allows editing of the first 130 characters of that same mp3 filename?  This did not happen in XP!  The problem occurs with both local and external drives.  The act of searching doesn't somehow add to the file-name's path does it?  I need to edit filenames in the search window (as I did with XP successfully) but now the search window results suddenly cannot be edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
The act of searching doesn't somehow add to the file-name's path does it?
```

No.

Can Right click->open file location->rename->back button work for you?